# How to use 're.serach' in pandas-dataframe for including"[" or "]"

Tags: pandas, python-re

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame([['a[]'],['a[] foo'],['a[] foo \n bar']],columns = ['a'])

txt = 'a[] foo \n bar'

def Function(x):
    if re.search(x, txt):
        return 'Match'
    else:
        return 'Nomatch'

df['match'] = df['a'].apply(Function)
```

df Table is below

[image]

In this case, I have gotten a following error code...

**error: unterminated character set at position 1**

How should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

You must escape the special characters:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame([['a\[]'],['a\[] foo'],['a\[] foo \n bar']],columns = ['a'])

txt = 'a[] foo \n bar'

def Function(x):
    if re.search(x, txt):
        return 'Match'
    else:
        return 'Nomatch'

df['match'] = df['a'].apply(Function)
```

out:

```
    a                 match
0   a\[]              Match
1   a\[] foo          Match
2   a\[] foo \n bar   Match
```